# Adding non-word allowances to WordDelimiterFilter

Tags: regex, solr, lucene

I'm implementing some Solr based solutions right now and am stuck on one point. I'm trying to take something like this: `IM extractor smooth wire 1.5x60cm` and split it into something like: `IM extractor smooth wire 1.5 60 cm`

The word based portion works a-okay quite easily, of course, thanks to the StandardTokenizerFactory. Easy breezy. The sticking point is the dimensions. Sometimes there will be 12mmx15mm wherein both dimensions have their prescribed measurement type (mm) associated with the qualifying number. Other times they'll just run together like in my example case.

As such, the WordDelimiterFilter would seem to come in handy to help break apart the numeric->alpha sequence into `12` and `mm`. The issue, though, is that it will break `1.5` into `1` and `5`, seeing the `.` as a delimiter.

I've tried CharPatternReplacement as well as adding those patterns to protected words for the WordDelimiterFilter to ignore (e.g. I had "QQ" replace any periods between digits using the pattern `(\d+)[.](\d+)`) but nothing I've tried thus far has gotten me to the goal tokenization.

Can I use a regex in the protected words file? Is there a filter that I've not considered that could help me split off the `mm` but not split the `1.5`?

Thanks for any thoughts!

---

*UPDATE*
I've come up with a solution, but it's not quite as elegant as I was hoping to employ. It's simply a stacking of PatternReplace CharFilters like so

```
<!-- space in place of mm -->
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(\d+)(mm|MM)" replacement="$1 $2"/>
        <!-- space in place of in -->
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(\d+)(in|IN)" replacement="$1 $2"/>
        <!-- space in place of cm -->
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(\d+)(cm|CM)" replacement="$1 $2"/>
```

It accomplishes the goal I had, but I'm certainly open to any better ways of solving this if you've got ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
([\d\.]+)x([\d\.]+)[ ]*cm
```

I'll explain

RegEx inside `()` is a capture group (the match you want to save)

This `[]` is a character class, meaning you specify one character that matches your pattern, in this case it's `\d` for any digit plus escaped dot `\.` for delimiter (you could add/switch with comma).

This character class can be repeated 1 - infinity times as specified by the + sign behind it.

The `x` is literal character, then we repeat the first capture group followed by any number of spaces followed by 'cm'